# How do I get msbuild to put my web application in the root output folder and not in _PublishedWebsites

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

How do I get msbuild to just put my web application in the output path, and not in the hacky special _PublishedWebsites folder? I don't want to modify global config files, but I am willing to edit my .csproj file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override WebProjectOutputDir to go to whatever directory you like, however the binaries will still be in this folder as well. Still trying to figure out how to fix that...

*EDIT* I ended up making my msbuild output directory my output directory with '/bin' tacked on to the end, and I made my WebProjectOutputDir the real output directory.